# How to search using an sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I find all the ids of an SQL table? For example I want to search for the word "key" and return the ids in which this word was found.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `id` is the name of a column in your table you would need to use `LIKE`

```
SELECT id 
FROM  YourTable
WHERE id LIKE '%key%'
```

The `%` is a wildcard meaning match any set of zero or more characters so this would find rows where the `id` value contains the substring (not necessarily word) "key".

Comment: thanks for you answer.can you tell me also where all these results will be saved?i mean the search results.

Comment: They wouldn't be saved anywhere unless you take steps to save them. What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: basically,i want to save them on the same sql database at another table probably

Comment: What generally i want to do is:If i have 80 ids with some content and when i search for a key it returns 20 results.I want to save these 20 results in a table and appear these on my page.

Comment: I don't understand why you need to save them in a table. You would just execute that query from php or whatever and loop through the result set to display on the page.

Comment: look,i want just to retrieve these results after from the database and appear them on my page.How can i retrieve them if they are not saved somewhere?that's all!

Comment: I think we were probably talking at cross purposes at the beginning. Your results won't be **saved** anywhere automatically but they will of course be accessible to your code that executes the query. There is no benefit of saving them in a table as you still need to query that table!

Comment: you mean that after the search i can appear them also?i think i will have trouble in coding.

Comment: Well if you can manage to write the code to display them from a table then you should be able to write the code to display them from a search query. What language are you writing your page in?

Comment: i know how to display them from a table but i believe it's different from a search query.Thank you for your advice.I haven't written my page yet but i am thinking on how to do the whole subject.

Comment: @user667628 - You still haven't answered what language/framework you are using (php, asp.net etc.) the one additional thing you need to be aware of is to use parameterised queries.

Comment: @user667628 - I'm not a PHP programmer but I believe that the safe way of doing queries in PHP is using PDO. If Google doesn't provide any good examples then ask another question on StackOverflow as to how you could integrate that query into a PHP page using PDO.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT [id field name] FROM [Tabel Name] WHERE [field to seach in for key] LIKE '%key%';

Comment: thanks for you answer.i am seeking a way to save the results in an other table on the database in order to retrieve them after on my page.Do you know any way?

Answer (score 0):

Would this be what you are looking for?

```
INSERT INTO dest_table (dest_id)
SELECT source_id
FROM source_table
WHERE source_column LIKE '%key%';
```

Comment: at a 90% this is what i want but i want also to print the results on the page.I think this code inserts on a new table and searches.

Comment: You don't need to insert the value in another database table then. You'll need to use a server-side script (like PHP or ASP) to query the database with the `SELECT` statement that was suggested by several persons here.